# Vue.js router-view mounted callback

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js with Vue-router in a project and I'm trying to have a callback whenever the routed-to component is ready. Usually you would do it inside each component in the **mounted()** hook, but for this case I want it for every component that has been routed to.

I tried with **router.OnReady()** and **router.afterEach()** but it did not work since they happen after routing but before the component is mounted. I also tried changing the vue-router source code adding **mounted()** to the router-view component, but it's not getting called.

Comment: I think you're looking for `router.beforeEach((to, from, next)) {` if you want to apply some global guards

Comment: Like I said, I need something after the component mounted.

Comment: Does the mounted() get called after the router changes it's location? I'm having an issue now where after I do a this.$router.push, mounted is not called on the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no on-router event for this but according to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1529) you can get around this by using `Vue.nextTick` inside `router.afterEach`.